# How to serialize the response to object by using Gson?

Tags: android, json, gson, vk, vk-sdk

I make request directly to `VK api` with `token`

Like this: `https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?fields=photo_50&access_token=MY_TOKEN&filter=admin%2C%20editor%2C%20moder&extended=1`
Here is  [spec about api](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=groups.get)
But I can't serialize the response to object by using `Gson`, because is response array there is `int` value:

```
{
    "response": [
        2,
        {
            "gid": 59295,
            "name": "Создание",
            "screen_name": "book",
            "is_closed": 0,
            "type": "group",
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/qwvD6SPkYzo.jpg"
        },
        {
            "gid": 57150,
            "name": "Массаж",
            "screen_name": "club10450",
            "is_closed": 2,
            "type": "group",
            "photo_50": "https://pp.userapi.com/ZKnmRkS1izs.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I make serialize it to object by using `Gson`?

Comment: Paste your model class also here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, Added param to url `v=5.61` [version number](https://vk.com/dev/versions)

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 190,
        "items": [{
            "id": 28261334,
            "name": "TJ",
            "screen_name": "tj",
            "is_closed": 0,
            "type": "page",
            "is_admin": 0,
            "is_member": 1,
            "photo_50": "https://pp.vk.me/...f2c/06crfCSL1KY.jpg"
            }]
    }
}
```

Comment: And how does JSON look like now?

Answer (score 1):

Despite you've already resolved the issue by changing the API version via the GET URL parameters, here is a method of dealing with "non-standard" JSONs you might face in the future. I'm assuming you have correct mappings, but the array length (presumably) is put as the very first array element. Gson cannot handle such a special case itself (at least if it expects `{...}` objects), probably giving you something like this:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 3 column 10 path $.response[0]

Assuming you have mappings similar to the next two:

```java
final class ElementsResponse {

    @SerializedName("response")
    final List<Element> response = null;

}
```

```java
final class Element {

    @SerializedName("gid")
    final int gid = Integer.valueOf(0);

    @SerializedName("name")
    final String name = null;

    @SerializedName("screen_name")
    final String screenName = null;

    @SerializedName("is_closed")
    final int isClosed = Integer.valueOf(0);

    @SerializedName("type")
    final String type = "";

    @SerializedName("photo_50")
    final URL photo50 = null;

}
```

You can easily create your type adapter with a special type adapter factory in order to deal with the given JSON:

```java
final class LengthArrayTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // The instance holds no state and can be created as a singleton    
    private static final TypeAdapterFactory lengthArrayTypeAdapterFactory = new LengthArrayTypeAdapterFactory();

    private LengthArrayTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    // However, the factory method does not let a caller to create an instance itself, and _may_ create it itself if necessary (encapsulation)
    static TypeAdapterFactory getLengthArrayTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return lengthArrayTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Are we dealing with a java.util.List instance?
        if ( List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            // Resolve the list element type if possible
            final Type elementType = getElementType(typeToken.getType());
            // And request Gson for the element type adapter
            final TypeAdapter<?> elementTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(elementType));
            // Some Java boilerplate regarding generics in order not letting the @SuppressWarnings annotation cover too much
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final TypeAdapter<T> castTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new LengthArrayTypeAdapter<>(elementTypeAdapter);
            return castTypeAdapter;
        }
        // Or let Gson pick the next downstream type adapter itself
        return null;
    }

    private static Type getElementType(final Type listType) {
        // The given type is not parameterized?
        if ( !(listType instanceof ParameterizedType) ) {
            // Probably the (de)serialized list is raw being not parameterized
            return Object.class;
        }
        final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) listType;
        // Or just take the first type parameter (java.util.List has one type parameter only)
        return parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    private static final class LengthArrayTypeAdapter<E>
            extends TypeAdapter<List<E>> {

        // This type adapter is designed to read and write a single element only
        // We'll take care of all elements array ourselves
        private final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter;

        private LengthArrayTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter) {
            this.elementTypeAdapter = elementTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public List<E> read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            // Gson type adapters are supposed to be null-friendly
            if ( in.peek() == NULL ) {
                return null;
            }
            // Consume the array begin token `[`
            in.beginArray();
            // The next value is most likely the array length?
            final int arrayLength = in.nextInt();
            final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
            // Read until the array has more elements
            while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                // And let the element type adapter read the array element so push the value to the list
                list.add(elementTypeAdapter.read(in));
            }
            // Consume the array end token `]`
            in.endArray();
            assert arrayLength == list.size();
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<E> list)
                throws IOException {
            if ( list == null ) {
                // Must be null-friendly always
                out.nullValue();
            } else {
                // Writing the `[` token
                out.beginArray();
                // Writing the list size/length
                out.value(list.size());
                for ( final E element : list ) {
                    // And just write each array element
                    elementTypeAdapter.write(out, element);
                }
                // Finalizing the writing with `]`
                out.endArray();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So all you had to do could be just adding the type adapter factory to the `Gson` configuration creating your special arrays-aware `Gson`:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getLengthArrayTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
final ElementsResponse elementsResponse = gson.fromJson(JSON, ElementsResponse.class);
elementsResponse.response.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.name));
System.out.println(gson.toJson(elementsResponse));
```

Output:

> Создание
>   Массаж
>   {"response":[2,{"gid":59295,"name":"Создание","screen_name":"book","is_closed":0,"type":"group","photo_50":"https://pp.userapi.com/qwvD6SPkYzo.jpg"},{"gid":57150,"name":"Массаж","screen_name":"club10450","is_closed":2,"type":"group","photo_50":"https://pp.userapi.com/ZKnmRkS1izs.jpg"}]}

Note that this type adapter factory always assumes that the first array element is a number, and you might need to analyze the `elementType` if necessary (for example, if it's a `java.lang.Number` or its subclass).